# loop optimization - rework

Tags: c, optimization

Considering the following pseudocode:

```
x1 = DEFAULT_VAL_1;
y1 = DEFAULT_VAL_2;
for (i = 0; i < CONST1; i++) {
    x0 = *x0buffer++;
    y0 = *y0buffer++;
    if (x0*y1 > y0*x1)
    {
        x1 = x0;
        y1 = y0;
        pos = i;
    }
}
```

and the outputs of interest `x1`, `y1` and `pos`,

could you recommend me a way to optimize it such that the `if` statement is avoided ?

Comment: Why obfuscate your code?

Comment: I'm assuming the 2nd row `y0 = ..` should have been `y1`, or...?

Comment: What is your target platform? Is `asm` an option?

Comment: If the compiler is competent it will use a conditional move for the three assignments, i.e. you likely won't get much better performance by removing the if.

Comment: I double checked the code, there isn't any typo. The platform is an embedded CPU and I can inline assembler code.

Comment: This is more of a math question, isn't it? Aside from understanding the code to see what the math problem is. EDIT: oops, I guess not if it's an assembler code question.

Comment: The if statement is like 1-3 cycles, so compared with multiplications which maybe around 30 cycles you should consider optimizing the multiplications and not the if statement. The if statment is like two instructions if you know assembly.

Comment: @valter You cannot compare it like that. You have to wait for the instruction and data fetch. It is not instanteous, and it might be not prefechted. The `cmp` itself might take 3 cycles,the execution of its body can take up to 100 of only waiting for memory.

Comment: @valter branches can cause a lot of pipeline stalls. While the two multiplications can be in the pipeline simultaneously on most modern CPUs.

Comment: The multiplications also take 1 cycle due to the specialized DSP architecture. A profile generated for that piece of code indicates almost three times more cycles for the `if` instruction than for the multiplies. Furthermore, because of the test condition, one extra cycle is wasted with nops because the data is available 1 cycle after the multiply.

Comment: I do agree with what you are saying but not all microprocessors have dedicated registers for multiplications. The majority with what i am programming dont have and multiplications are a factor, not a big one but you have to be carefull.

Comment: You're talking about architecture-specific effects without sharing with us the architecture.  Is it a secret?

Comment: Indeed, the architecture is not openly available, though it shouldn't differ much from a standard dsp arch; also I tried to un-relate the code to the platform and seek an algorithm-based solution, but someone asked me about the target platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on x86, you don't trust your compiler to optimise this and you are willing to go into assembly then this will do the trick:

```
x1 = DEFAULT_VAL_1;
y1 = DEFAULT_VAL_2;
for (i = 0; i < CONST1; i++) {
    x0 = *x0buffer++;
    y0 = *y0buffer++;

    asm (
        "cmp %3, %4\n\t"
        "cmovl %5, %0\n\t"
        "cmovl %6, %1\n\t"
        "cmovl %7, %2\n\t"
        : "+g" (pos)
        , "+g" (x1)
        , "+g" (y1)
        : "r" (x0*y1)
        , "r" (y0*x1)
        , "r" (i)
        , "r" (x0)
        , "r" (y0)
        : "cc"
    );
}
```

Comment: The platform is not x86, but the compiler generates code similar to yours, with a conditional jump over the three moves. I am looking for some alternative solution (another algorithm) that could squeeze even 1 cycle, as the code resides on the 4th level of some nested loops.

Comment: conditional jumps cause pipeline stalls. conditional moves (like the ones I used above) do not. This is far better if your branch predictor misses. Look in your processor manual if you have a similar instruction.

Comment: Values are compared, but branching is avoided completely. They are the evil things, not the `cmp`, which behaves basically like a `sub` without stroring the result.

Comment: The profile report indicates slightly less cycles using conditionals, so thanks.I'll test your other solution and compare them; do you think it'll work for fixed point numbers as well (Q24:23) ?

Comment: I get much better results on another piece of code using the same idea to replace gotos with conditionals. All in all, it's a nice tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version

```
   for (i = 0; i < CONST1; i++) {
    x0 = *x0buffer++;
    y0 = *y0buffer++;
    c = (x0*y1 > y0*x1);

        x1 = x0 *c + x1 * (c^1);
        y1 = y0 *c + y1 * (c^1);
        pos = i* c + pos * (c^1);    
}
```

It may seem like the code is much more computationally intensive, but on a parrallel architecture this will execute faster than the original version.

Hope it helps

Comment: The lack of implicit conversion from bool to int/fixed point demanded more adjustments that took additional cycles. Furthermore, my compiler didn't do such a great job parallelizing the code, and I don't think I have the skills to optimize it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bytes are 8 bit long (modify as necessary) and your integers have their sign in the MSB then this may or may not be faster:

```
#define masked_replace(mask, a, b) a += ( (b) - (a) ) & (mask)

int mask = y0*x1 - x0*y1; // signed(!!!) int
mask >>= sizeof(mask) * 8 - 1;
masked_replace(mask, x1, x0);
masked_replace(mask, y1, y0);
masked_replace(mask, pos, i);
```